# Why is my rspec test failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

Here's the test:

```
        describe "admin attribute" do

        before(:each) do
          @user = User.create!(@attr)
        end

        it "should respond to admin" do
          @user.should respond_to(:admin)
        end

        it "should not be an admin by default" do
          @user.should_not be_admin
        end

        it "should be convertible to an admin" do
          @user.toggle!(:admin)
          @user.should be_admin
        end
      end
```

Here's the error:

```
  1) User password encryption admin attribute should respond to admin
 Failure/Error: @user = User.create!(@attr)
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Email has already been taken
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:128
```

I'm thinking the error might be somewhere in my data populator code:

```
require 'faker'

namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task :populate => :environment do
    Rake::Task['db:reset'].invoke
    admin = User.create!(:name => "Example User",
                 :email => "example@railstutorial.org",
                 :password => "foobar",
                 :password_confirmation => "foobar")
    admin.toggle!(:admin)             
    99.times do |n|
      name  = Faker::Name.name
      email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
      password  = "password"
      User.create!(:name => name,
                   :email => email,
                   :password => password,
                   :password_confirmation => password)
    end
  end
end
```

Please let me know if I should reproduce any more of my code.

UPDATE: Here's where `@attr` is defined, at the top of the `user_spec.rb` file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before(:each) do
      @attr = { 
        :name => "Example User", 
        :email => "user@example.com",
        :password => "foobar",
        :password_confirmation => "foobar" 
      }
    end
```

Comment: Where is `@attr` being defined? Can you post its contents?

Comment: Also, I'm following http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#top if it's of any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check to be sure that there isn't a block further up your `user_spec.rb` that is calling `User.create` in a `before(:each)` block with the same email address. If your blocks are nested incorrectly, you'll get this error. For example, in the Rails tutorial, it's easy to accidentally nest your `describe "admin attribute"` inside your `describe "password encryption"` block, which uses the same `before(:each)` code.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right, but I couldn't figure out where my nesting had gone wrong so I simply deleted the `before(:each)` block in my `describe "admin attribute"` block and now my test passes

Comment: In that case then it's *definitely* a nesting issue, or your test wouldn't pass because `@user` would be `nil`. :) Here's my [complete `user_spec.rb` from the tutorial](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/rails-book/blob/master/spec/models/user_spec.rb#files), if it helps.

Comment: Ahh thanks, that really helped a lot. I was missing a stupid `end` somewhere and it was throwing everything off. Thanks Brandon.

Comment: good catch, couldn't believe I miss this until I watch the screencast again

Answer (score 2):

Try checking for existing users in the before block:

```
before(:each) do
  User.count.should == 0
  @user = User.create!(@attr)
end
```

If that fails, then another user exists with the same email. This could be because another before block created a user with the same attributes, or that the test database was not correctly cleaned out after a failure. For the latter case, try running `rake db:test:prepare`, and then run the spec again.

Answer (score 0):

`before( :each )` is going to create a new user object from @attr. So if @attr isn't changing the values for its fields, and you have validations turned on to prevent duplicate, then on your 2nd test, the user object you created in the first test will collide with the one you are trying to create in the 2nd test.

There are other ways to go about testing your model without the database. For example, you can use test doubles to create and setup objects with exactly the data you want and then run your test to see if it behaves correctly. There is a [great book on RSpec, Cucumber and BDD] that could be a great source.

Edit: My apologies, I was confusing `before(:each)` with `before(:all)`.

Comment: So I should just delete the `before(:each)` block?

Comment: The test database is reset between examples, so this cannot be the cause.

Comment: Yeah, I realized I was confusing `before(:each)` with `before(:all)`

Answer (score 0):

This does not seems to be ideal way of setting up test data. ie, using a rake task to populate the database.

A more standard unit testing and Rails practice would be to use both [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) or a test_fixture and transactional test fixture or [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem.

Read a little bit about those, and they should be straight forward to use. They ensure, that each of your rspec test runs in isolation even when you run all of them together. That way, each test data for one test will not affect the other one.

Comment: And btw you can still continue to use faker gem with factory_girl